# Greater than operator &gt in Hana

Tags: sql-server, xml, hana

I'm passing Sql Staments from Ms sql server to Sap Hana Sintaxis (There are inside an xml file) so I'm confused because I can't can't figure out:

Which is the equivalen in SAP Hana for &gt?

&gt --> Greater than (used when the sql staments are inside an XML file)

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert it back to a >, because it's an xml escape sequence.

Comment: sorry I don't understand you @Kevin Cook