# Greater than operator in Hana

Tags: sql-server, xml, hana

I have a sql query inside a XML File and I need to use the comparision operator GREATER THAN but with this syntax "&gt" The sql conversor I'm using from Ms Sql Server to HANA displays an error with &gt

Question: Does Hana support &gt operator?

because I have the sql query inside a xml file I CAN'T USE the > syntax because > is closing sign for XML syntax instead I have to use &gt

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks very like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083459/greater-than-operator-gt-in-hana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to solve your problem by making use of cdata sections in your XML document.  In particular, you would want to wrap your queries in cdata sections.  For example:

```
<root>
    <query>
    <![CDATA[
    select vbeln from vbpa where posnr > 50.
    ]]>
    </query>
</root>
```

For more about cdata sections refer to this question: [What does <![CDATA[]]> in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean)

Answer (score 1):

The > operator in HANA is definitely supported. It shouldn't be a problem, bust just to be sure: Check if the file which stores the sql query has a correct encoding.

It could also be a syntax error in your sql query. Please post the query and, more important, the error message.

**Edit**:
A character entity reference is always ending with a semicolon. Try if `&gt;` works for you.

Comment: youre are right the > operator is supported in Hana. (Please Check my edit).. because I have the sql query inside a xml file I CAN'T USE the > syntax because > is closing sign for XML syntax @shofmn

Comment: @user1629278 I edited my post. Check if that solution works for you.

Comment: you are rigth I added the semicolon... but Still don't know it HANA support the &gt because the SQL Conversor displays an error with the input contains that carácter @shofmn